# RecyclerView Observer, fragment not updating data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewmodel

My MainFragment contains a RecyclerView of educational paths, when an item is selected it takes the user to CourseFragment with a different RecyclerView of relevant courses. However, if the user goes back to the first RecyclerView and chooses a different path, the same data items show up again.

Course Fragment

```
class CourseFragment : Fragment(),
    CourseRecyclerAdapter.CourseItemListener {

    private lateinit var viewModel: CourseViewModel
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Course Fragment onCreateView(): selectedItem = $globalSelectedPath")

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_course, container, false)
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.courseRecyclerView)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.nav_host )
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(CourseViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.courseData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            val adapter =
                CourseRecyclerAdapter(
                    requireContext(),
                    it,
                    this
                )
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        } )
        return view
    }
```

CourseViewModel

```
class CourseViewModel(app: Application): AndroidViewModel(app) {

    private val courseDataRepository = CourseRepository(app)
    val courseData = courseDataRepository.courseData
    val selectedCourse = MutableLiveData<Course>()
}
```

Course Repository

```
class CourseRepository(val app: Application) {

    val courseData = MutableLiveData<List<Course>>()

    init {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            callWebService()
        }
    }

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun callWebService() {
        if (Utility.networkAvailable(app)) {

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(WEB_SERVICE_URL).addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create()).build()
            val service = retrofit.create(CourseService::class.java)
            val serviceData = service.getCourseData(globalSelectedPath).body() ?: emptyList()
            courseData.postValue(serviceData)
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(app, Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.noConnectivity), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

I added some logs and noticed that my Repository is only called once the app opens up first time, but never fetches the data again because the callWebService() is never called again.

```
12:24:02.520 I/mylog: Course Fragment onCreateView(): selected path = MOB001
12:24:02.529 I/mylog: Course Repository callWebService(): selected path = MOB001
-------------------------------
12:24:35.009 I/mylog: Course Fragment onCreateView(): selected path = WEB999
```

I added some http logs to trace data and confirmed that the data was being retrieved once only:

```
12:24:02.551 D/OkHttp: --> GET https://.../mobile/feed/course_data.php?pathName=MOB001
12:24:02.551 D/OkHttp: --> END GET
12:24:03.007 D/OkHttp: <-- 200 https://.../mobile/feed/course_data.php?pathName=MOB001 (455ms)
12:24:03.007 D/OkHttp: date: Sat, 02 May 2020 09:24:03 GMT
12:24:03.007 D/OkHttp: server: Apache
12:24:03.007 D/OkHttp: x-powered-by: PHP/5.6.40
12:24:03.007 D/OkHttp: vary: Accept-Encoding
12:24:03.007 D/OkHttp: content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
12:24:03.009 D/OkHttp: [{"courseName":"Android App Development Essentials","instructor":"John Lennon","courseDescription":"Description ...","courseImage":"android_development_essentials.jpg","instructorImage":"john.jpg"}]
12:24:03.009 D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (206-byte body)
```

Comment: When were you expecting it to be called? You only call it once.

Comment: @ianhanniballake, when i return to the main fragment and choose another item, which navigates me back to the second fragment, it should be called again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(CourseViewModel::class.java)`, which means you're creating your `CourseViewModel` scoped to the entire activity. That means there will only be one instance of `CourseViewModel` created for the entire lifetime of the activity.

If you want a separate `CourseViewModel` (and hence, a separate `CourseRepository` instance) for each fragment, you should use `ViewModelProvider(this)` to scope the ViewModel to the fragment itself:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CourseViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: Unbelievable, it actually worked! I cannot believe such a small issue has been holding me up for days. Thank you immensely.